# Finding the smallest closest value in an array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the code as below

```
    var searchValues = new double[] { 21.1, 21.65, 22.2, 22.75, 23.3, 23.85, 24.4, 24.95, 25.5, 26.05, 26.6, 27.15, 27.7, 28.25, 28.8, 29.35, 29.9, 30.45, 31, 31.55, 32.1, 32.65, 33.2, 33.75, 34.3, 34.85, 35.4, 35.95 };
    var searchValue = 22;

  double nearest = searchValues .Select(p => new { Value = p, Difference = Math.Abs(p - searchValue ) })
                                  .OrderBy(p => p.Difference)
                                  .First().Value;
```

This code returns me 22.2 . However i want the result to be the smallest value close to 22, i.e it will be 21.65. How do i achieve this? I am relatively new to C# and would appreciate some help.

Comment: One value generally can't be at the same time "the closest to X" and "have the smallest absolute value"... Please re-read the question and see if some [edit] can clarify what you want to achieve (which should not be "just look at values less than X")

Comment: What is expected nearest value if `searchValue` is `10`?

Comment: Only by reading the title and seeing input arguments, it is unclear to me, what are you trying to achieve with the last part.

Comment: If you only want values that are smaller than searchValue, you can apply an where clause to your search: `double nearest = searchValues.Where(x => x < searchValue).Select(p => new{Value = p, Difference = Math.Abs(p - searchValue)}).OrderBy(p => p.Difference).First().Value;`. Not that this will fail if not smaller value was found. You will have to check that. If this is not what you are looking for I also do not get your actual problem as 21.65 is the nearest number without any other condition.

Comment: As @AlexeiLevenkov already said, kindly re-write your question so that it will be easy to understand others what you are looking for. You are looking for `"closest value which is less than X"`. Your code and input, expected output is saying something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your expected output you are trying to find closed value which is **less than** `searchValue`. Try below

```
var searchValues = new double[] { 21.1, 21.65, 22.2, 22.75, 23.3, 23.85, 24.4, 24.95, 25.5, 26.05, 26.6, 27.15, 27.7, 28.25, 28.8, 29.35, 29.9, 30.45, 31, 31.55, 32.1, 32.65, 33.2, 33.75, 34.3, 34.85, 35.4, 35.95 };
var searchValue = 22;

double nearest = searchValues
    .Where(x => x <= searchValue)  //Filter all values which are less than or equal to searchValue
    .OrderBy(y=> y)               //Order resultant values by ascending order
    .LastOrDefault();             //Get the max value from an array.

Console.WriteLine(nearest == 0 && searchValue > 0 ? "Invalid Input" : $"Nearest Value : {nearest}");
```

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mS4ViT)

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what i was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply Math.Round() in difference.

```
       var searchValues = new double[] { 21.1, 21.65, 22.2, 22.75, 23.3, 
                          23.85, 24.4, 24.95, 25.5, 26.05, 26.6, 27.15, 27.7, 
                          28.25, 28.8, 29.35, 29.9, 30.45, 31, 31.55, 32.1, 
                          32.65, 33.2, 33.75, 34.3, 34.85, 35.4, 35.95 };
        var searchValue = 22;

        double nearest = searchValues.Select(p => new { Value = p, Difference 
                                   = Math.Round(Math.Abs(p - searchValue)) })
                                        .OrderBy(p => p.Difference)
                                        .First().Value;

        Console.WriteLine(nearest);
```

Comment: Above code snippet gives desired output as you want